# Sed seems to replace only the last occurrence in global string substitution

Tags: sed, regex-greedy

I use this command, but it's not working ad intended:

```
echo "0+223+141+800+450+1*(106+400)+1*(1822+500)+1*(183+400)" | sed 's/\*\(.*\)+/*\1suma/g'
```

This is the expected output:

```
0+223+141+800+450+1*(106suma400)+1*(1822suma500)+1*(183suma400)
```

but this is what I get:

```
0+223+141+800+450+1*(106+400)+1*(1822+500)+1*(183suma400)
```

It looks like only the last occurrence is being replaced, despite the use of `g`.

Comment: The title says "awk", but the question and the tag are about sed. Also, "not work" is not helpful – what happens exactly? What's your output?

Comment: 0+223+141+800+450+1*(106+400)+1*(1822+500)+1*(183suma400)

Comment: only change the last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo "0+223+141+800+450+1*(106+400)+1*(1822+500)+1*(183+400)" |
    sed 's/\(\*([^+]*\)+/\1suma/g'
```

which yields:

```
0+223+141+800+450+1*(106suma400)+1*(1822suma500)+1*(183suma400)
```

The trick is to avoid `sed`'s invariably *greedy* matching, so expression `[^+]*` is used instead of `.*`, so as to only match up to the *next* `+`.

---

Note that your attempt didn't only replace the *last* occurrence of your intended pattern, but - due to greedy matching - found only *1* match spanning *multiple* intended patterns, which it replaced:

`\*\(.*\)+` matched `*(106+400)+1*(1822+500)+1*(183+` - everything from the first `*` literal to the *last* `+` literal, and capture group `\1` therefore expanded to `(106+400)+1*(1822+500)+1*(183`